# Difference between $Q$ value and Total energy in a beta minus decay

Tags: energy, nuclear-physics, radiation, neutrinos

I was going through the kinematics of beta minus decay. I understood that the $Q$ value in the beta minus decay is the sum of the KE of electron and anti-neutrino

$$Q= E_e + E_\nu.$$ Here the $E_e$ and $ E\nu$ are the KE of the electron and antineutrino.

I derived the basic energy-momenta spectra of beta minus decay and obtained the expression as

$$N(E_e)=K*\sqrt(E_e^2+2E_em_ec^2)(Q-E_e)^2(E_e+m_ec^2)$$ which later I found is the standard energy momenta spectra shape of beta minus decay.

However, in some papers the beta spectra is given as

$P=Kp_\beta E_\beta (E_o-E_\beta)^2$  and it is given that $E_o=Q+m_ec^2-E_n$ where $E_n$ is the excitation energy of the daughter nucleus.

I checked many papers and books and found that my formula of beta minus decay is correct. But I do not know how to bring the second form of the expression which I actually needed. Basically I have to calculate the anti neutrino spectra from this which comes as

$P_\bar{\nu}=KE_\bar{\nu}^2(E_o-E_\bar{\nu})\sqrt([(E_o-E\bar{\nu})^2-m_ec^2])$ replacing $E_e$ with $(E_o-E\bar{\nu})$

Can anyone please help me how I can obtain this form of the expression
$P=Kp_\beta E_\beta (E_o-E_\beta)^2$?